# How to add all fields in an object in JSON in NodeJS?

Tags: arrays, node.js, json

```
[{
   "description" : "sample",
   "link" : "mylink",
   "id" :"1",
   "deviceName":"mydevice1"
},
{
   "description" : "sample",
   "link" : "mylink",
   "id" :"1",
   "deviceName":"mydevice1"
},
{
   "description" : "sample",
   "link" : "mylink",
   "id" :"",
   "deviceName":""
}]
```

Above is my current `JSON` i want to modify it to

```
{"Items":[{
   "description" : "sample",
   "link" : "mylink",
   "id" :"1",
   "deviceName":"mydevice1"
},
{
   "description" : "sample",
   "link" : "mylink",
   "id" :"1",
   "deviceName":"mydevice1"
},
{
   "description" : "sample",
   "link" : "mylink",
   "id" :"",
   "deviceName":""
}]}
```

Right now i am achieving this using string manipulation, But i feel it is not the right way to do it.How do i achieve this desired result more efficiently? is it possible ? any help is highly appreciated :) thanks guys

Comment: You could JSON.parse the file into a variable "content" and create another object const container = { "Items": content } and write it to a file with JSON.stringify

Comment: const result = { "items" : your_object_name }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```js
const items = [{
   "description" : "sample",
   "link" : "mylink",
   "id" :"1",
   "deviceName":"mydevice1"
},
{
   "description" : "sample",
   "link" : "mylink",
   "id" :"1",
   "deviceName":"mydevice1"
},
{
   "description" : "sample",
   "link" : "mylink",
   "id" :"",
   "deviceName":""
}];

const desiredStructure = {
  "Items" : items
}
```

The `JSON` structure you want is in the `desiredStructure` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can add elements as you want by using this.

```js
const items = [];
items.push({"description" : "sample","link" : "mylink","id" :"1","deviceName":"mydevice1"});
items.push({"description" : "sample","link" : "mylink","id" :"1","deviceName":"mydevice1"});
items.push({"description" : "sample","link" : "mylink","id" :"1","deviceName":"mydevice1"});
const desiredStructure = {
  "Items" : items
} 
console.log(desiredStructure);
```